# Where are these methods being called from?

Tags: java, methods, scope, polymorphism

Okay so consider an Interface

```
interface Action {
    void doSomething();
}
```

And a class implementing the interface

```
class Greeting implements Action {

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello, World!" ;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(getGreeting());
    }

}
```

Now if I create a reference of the interface and assign it the class's object

```
Action action = new Greeting();
action.doSomething(); // Calls the getGreeting() method and prints it.
```

How does this work ?

Comment: You've explicitly asked for just the interface, `Actions` when you do this: `Action action = new Greeting();`. Any additional methods implemented by subclasses using the interface are off limits.

Comment: you define action variabe from Action type, so can not see getGreeting() method. In Greeting class, method getGreeting() can be accessed as a local method.

Comment: `Greeting implements Actions`. Should't it be `Action` instead of `Actions`?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable `action` of type `Action`.

This means that you can only use methods that are part of that interface.

When you call it, it is delegated to your implementation, i.e. `Greeting`

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing that error because `action` is of type `Action` and that type doesn't have a `getGreeting()` method.

If you need access to `getGreeting()` either declare `action` as a `Greeting`:

```
Greeting action = new Greeting();
action.getGreeting(); //should work
```

Or cast the `action` to a `Greeting`:

```
Action action = new Greeting();
((Greeting)action).getGreeting(); //Again, should work
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned your object of `Greeting` to `Action` type. Although the object of `Greeting` has the method `getGreeting()` but the `Action` type does not understand it.

That's the reason when you try on `Action` object, `getGreeting` method is not supported.